# I am getting 500 internal server error htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to MVC (just learning) and I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYxw7-zQaV8&list=PLU6gyrizgE6rTrd5K-U94UryjYIQ1GfDd&index=3

I am using MAMP

my root directory is MAMP/htdocs/

my mvc project is in MAMP/htdocs/MVC

one of my htaccess file is in MAMP/htdocs/MVC - which redirects request to .../MVC/webroot

My htaccess file which is in MVC folder is as follows:

#turn on the engine
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^$ webroot [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1  [L]
```

My other htaccess file in the webroot directory is as follows:

RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteCond % [REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f  
RewriteCond % [REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d    


RewriteRule ^{.*}$  index.php [PT,L]
```

PLease help me I stressed out. I wanted to learn this and I am stuck since afternoon.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check your server error logs. Check MAMP to find out where this would be stored. A 500 error by itself is way too broad and could be any number of things.

Comment: Is it definitely you're `.htaccess` file that's the issue? Also, are you on a mac or windows?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but that tutorial has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look at your htaccess with a linter (I used http://www.htaccesscheck.com/ ):

```
RewriteCond % [REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f  
RewriteCond % [REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
```

That seems wrong!
Try this syntax:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

(mind the `{` vs your `[` )

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MVC/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /MVC/webroot/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The IfModule tag is to make sure that the rewrite module is enabled so you do not run into htaccess error.